# GTAV launcher error

Tags: launcher, games

Whenever I try to launch GTA V, it open the rockstar launcher however it says I have some running already, i wiped the computer and tried again and it gave me the same error.

I have tried, reinstalling, verifying the game files, wiping, running through the command prompt, nothing worked.

I have also contacted rockstar games but never got a response.

How do i fix it so it launches properly?

****I am on the latest ubuntu and i have had it work before, this problem is just very recent****

Comment: Looking at the steam product page for this game, it only has a Windows client...

Comment: I'm confused, are you using Linux or Windows?  GTA has no Linux launcher and only a windows client.  It is not Steam Play certified either so it's not guaranteed to work via Steam on Linux

Comment: well i got it working several times, by using proton. so yes it works on linux as well. but it has more issues than windows. this problem was just very recent

Comment: Where is the version of Ubuntu in your question. All available resources says it does not work or is supported but guess you know better.

Comment: its the latest one i think, 18. whatever or something

Answer (score 1):

OK, so i figured it out, i just needed to download an older launcher of the game and then it worked. however it does run but i want to access the social app without having to run the game or signing in though the web. so how do i make a .exe work?

(im on the latest ubuntu patch)

*** AND YES GTAV WORKS ON LINUX! YOU HAVE TO USE PROTON AND INSTALL AN OLDER LAUNCHER. YES ITLL CORRUPT OFTEN BUT IT WORKS!***

Comment: Good job getting it to work. You might want to ask a new question for your follow-up question (but I suspect you're more likely to get help on a forum for the game)

Comment: alright will do thanks